# livereload (или watch) для nodejs

Tags: node.js, vim, tmux

Использую nodejs для отладки кода (вместо привычной консоли Firefox, нужно просто выводить  в node результат console.log). Есть ли возможность подобия livereload (или watch) для node? Каждый раз набирать CTRl-b > l > стрелка вверх > enter потом возврат назад  в редактор  CTRL-b > h утомительно.
Использую vim+tmux.

Comment: Есть очень много разных библиотек, в гугле ищутся по любому запросу. Есть как и модули для gulp/grunt, есть и отдельные библиотеки, например: https://github.com/napcs/node-livereload

Comment: Ваш вариант предполагает использование браузера и сервера. У меня  только редактор и терминал. Нужно похожее на компиляцию babel или coffescript, node компилирует их в live режиме без браузера и сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Я использую [пакет](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-live-reload), устанавливаемый вот так: npm install -g node-live-reload. Когда знакомился с js на сервере, вот [эту](https://habrahabr.ru/post/168091/) статью читал.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/125125)

Comment: npm пакеты имеют перелинковку в случае их изменения, хабр - тут без комментариев, статья старая, никуда (разве что с хабром) не денется.